# Google analytics custom report and/or filters

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having a problem creating custom report. Is there an option to filters to ad 'or' not only 'and' other Page. Actually I need to trace the every page that starts with www.web.com/page1/ but I haw also a multi language page so can bi a www.web.com/en/page1/ or www.web.com/ge/page1/ or www.web.com/fr/page1/ and so on with eight different languages. Is there way to trace them all with one report?    [image: Filters]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had to do this myself. Here's what to do for the filter:

(1) For the first field, set **Include**.

(2) For the second field, set **Page**.

(3) For the third field, set **Regex**.

(4) For the fourth field, enter a regular expression that matches all of the OR clauses you need to filter on and nothing else. In the case of your example (assuming all your language codes are 2 characters):

```
^/[A-Za-z]{2}/page1/$
```

This will match everything on your website that has two characters where the language code is located in your question.

Another option is to filter out exact values. You can also do this with a regex. To include the "en" and "fr" language codes only:

```
^/en/page1/$|^/fr/page1/$
```

Notice that the pipe character is used as an OR statement between two complete regular expressions here.

Hope this helps anyone else doing this!